# QML Create a component dynamically by mouse press and drag it to a new location

Tags: javascript, qt, drag-and-drop, qml

Good day!

There is an element when you click on which a new element is created:
main.qml

```
Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")
Rectangle
{
    id: black

    x: 200
    y: 200

    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "black"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressed:
        {
            var pos = mapToItem(black.parent, mouse.x, mouse.y)
            createNew(pos)

        }

        function createNew(pos) {
            var comp = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/src/qml/NewElement.qml");
            if (comp.status !== Component.Ready)
            {
                console.log("Error creating component");
            }


            var link = comp.createObject(black.parent, { x: pos.x, y: pos.y, z:100});

            if (link === null) {
                console.log("Error creating object");
            }

            return link
        }
    }
}
}
```

There is a new element that can be dragged:
New Element.qml

```
Item {
id: red

width: 30
height: 30

Rectangle
{
    anchors.fill: parent

    color: "red"
}

MouseArea
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    drag.target: red
    drag.axis: Drag.XandYAxis
}

}
```

Аfter creating the element, you need to click on the element again to drag it.
Question:
How to make it so that after creating an element, it can be immediately dragged (with the mouse button pressed)

Comment: Note: Creating a component dynamically could take time depending on how complex your component is. You're checking for the `Ready` status, but it might still be in the `Loading` state.

Comment: @JarMan If the QML file to be loaded with Qt.createComponent is a local file you can call createObject() immediately: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html

Comment: @talamaki Thanks for the link. I see that in the documentation, but it strangely has not been my experience. Maybe on older versions there was a bug or something. I have definitely run into situations where I had to wait for my components to finish getting created, so that's been my habit ever since.

Comment: Right, I actually always handle asynchronous case too by connecting to statusChanged signal of component even my experience has been they always get created synchronously. Looking at documentation there seems to be room for uncertainty: "Scenarios that may cause asynchronous loading include, but are not limited to..." https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createComponent-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Drag.*` attached properties, something like this:

```js
Rectangle {
    id: container
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "orange"

    Component {
        id: itemComponent
        Rectangle {
            width: 50
            height: 50
            border.color: "grey"
            radius: 5
            color: "lightblue"
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: (mouse)=> {
                       addItem(mouse.x, mouse.y);
                   }
        onReleased: {
            Drag.active = false;
        }

        function addItem(x, y)
        {
            var obj = itemComponent.createObject(container, { x: x - 25, y: y - 25 });
            mouseArea.drag.target = obj;
            Drag.active = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I need to call MouseArea::positionChanged signal in a creatable Item because I use a specific functionality. Can you tell me how I can do this?

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean. Please create another question, provide [mcve] and explain the issue.

Comment: Ok, my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72632210/qml-pass-mouse-events-to-the-created-element-by-pressing-press