# QML Pass mouse events to the created element by pressing press

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have an element that creates a new element by the onPressed event, the created element has its own MouseArea with the functions onPressed and onPositionChanged.
Now I have to press on the new element again to interact with it.
How can I make the new element react immediately to mouse events (when the mouse button is pressed)?

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

Rectangle
{
    id: start

    width: 100
    height: 100
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

    color: "red"

    Component
    {
        id: comp
        Rectangle
        {
            x: start.x
            y: start.y

            width: start.width
            height: start.height



            color: "blue"

            MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent

                onPositionChanged:
                {
                    console.log(mouse.x, mouse.y)
                    if (mouse.x < 0)
                    {
                        parent.x += mouse.x
                    }
                    if (mouse.y < 0)
                    {
                        parent.y += mouse.y
                    }
                    if (mouse.x > parent.width)
                    {
                        parent.x += mouse.x - parent.width
                    }
                    if (mouse.y > parent.height)
                    {
                        parent.y += mouse.y - parent.height
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        property Item obj

        onPressed: {
            obj = comp.createObject(start.parent);

            if (obj === null) {
                console.log("Error creating object");
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: what do you try do in your `onPositionChanged` handler? what a reaction that you expect and what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @folibis
onPositionChanged works correctly (the mouse does not move the rectangle when the cursor is inside, and moves the rectangle when the cursor goes beyond it), but I want:
1. the user clicks on the red rectangle (without releasing the button)
2. a blue rectangle is created
3. the user move the cursor out of the rectangle (also without releasing the button), and the blue rectangle begins to move
4. If the user clicks on the blue rectangle again, it will behave the same way.